# How to get the right output for this using by lambda function?

Tags: python-2.7

```
a = raw_input()
if len(a) == 0:
    pass
else:
    n = divmod(len(a), 10)
    for i in range(1, n[0]+1):
        a = a[:i*10 + (lambda x: x=i-1)] + '\n' + a[i*10 + (lambda x: x=i-1):]
    print a
```

In the problem, I want to get divided sentences for every 10 strings when I put the sentences into this python code.

I wanted to get the result by using lambda function on this at first, but the error raised like this,

```
a = a[:i*10 + (lambda x: x=i-1)] + '\n' + a[i*10 + (lambda x: x=i-1):]
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

for now, I know something went wrong on the part of lambda function for this problem, but I can't correct this code rightly. please help!

Comment: Why are you trying to use a lambda expression (as opposed to the value computed BY a lambda expression) in specifying a slice?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a need for lambda functions here.  If you are interested in lambdas, checkout out a tutorial like this one: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/anonymous-function

Comment: I wanted to use lambda function because when I tried to slice sentences, '\n' was added to the sentences. so when I tried to slice the sentence which length is over 20, two '\n' are added to original sentence.

Comment: as a result of the number of '\n's, 10 strings are printed at the first line, and 9 strings are printed at other lines.

Answer (score 0):

how about this

```
>>> t='abra cadabra'
>>> n=3
>>> print "\n".join( t[i:(i+n)] for i in range(0,len(t),n) )
abr
a c
ada
bra
>>>
```